# Debugging Silverlight when hosted in a web project?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, debugging, .net-3.5, silverlight-3.0

This is probably a basic question.

I have two projects:

1. A web application project, that has a webpage that hosts a Silverlight application, as well as a web service
2. A Silverlight application project, the one hosted in the above web application

If I debug the Silverlight application, it wants to run this with a generated web page, which will of course not start my web application, and web service calls fails due to some cross-site security model. So even if I have the web application running, the Silverlight application won't use it.

If I debug the Web application (that is, set it as a start project and hit Debug), then the Silverlight application is apparently correctly hosted, but I can't debug it. Any breakpoints in it shows up as those hollow circles.

So what am I doing wrong? How should I configure my projects so that I can start the web application, host my Silverlight application, and debug it?

I'm betting it is one of those "dough" moments when someone tells me, but I can't figure it out.

This is Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5 and Silverlight 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to run the web app and debug the silverlight app.

Make sure you have silverlight debugging on in your project properties (not sure which project)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983445.aspx

Its a flag under

Project Properties > Web > Debuggers > Sivlerlight

Comment: Yup, as I said, basic. Thanks!